# Python type annotation where second argument refers to the first

Tags: python-3.x, types, annotations, mypy

I have the below Python function for which I'm trying to determine the correct annotations. The second argument derives it's type from the first argument.

```
        def q( type, func : Callable[[type], str]) -> bool:
            nonlocal text
            if isinstance( node, type ):
                text = func( node )
                return True
            return False
```

It's part of a visitor pattern that matches an object to the correct type and then dispatches to a function that accepts that type. I use it like below.

```
        _ = \
            q( doc_tree.Block, self._get_block ) or \
            q( doc_tree.Section, self._get_section ) or \
            q( doc_tree.Text, self._get_text ) or \
            fail()
```

The functions look like this:

```
    def _get_section( self, node : doc_tree.Section ) -> str:
```

The call to `q( doc_tree.Section, self._get_section )` fails in `mypy` with the error:

```
error: Argument 2 to "q" has incompatible type "Callable[[Section], str]"; expected "Callable[[type], str]"
```

How can I properly annotate the types in the `q` function?

Answer (score 1):

You want a `TypeVar`:

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

def q( type: T, func : Callable[[T], str]) -> bool: ...
```